# Transfer files between Mac/Windows and Iphone App

Tags: ios, bonjour

I'm working on Iphone App and would like to transfer files(pdf, image, txt) between Mac/Window and My Iphone app,

I would like good suggestions the "best way" to do:
I knew there are something called Bonjour in Mac, but I did not know much about the detail and how hard to implement in my iphone app in order to exchange files between Mac/Windows and my App.

Any suggestion would be appreciated and Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what is the use case?

Answer (score 1):

AirDrop, introduced in iOS7, is a great Bluetooth transfer library.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Are you sure that it's possible to transfer files between iOS application and Mac by Airdrop? Code sample that you've provided is related to transferring data between iOS devices.

Comment: Window does't support AirDrop? please correct me if it is not the case

Comment: From what I can find you are right. I don't think there is a 'best way' to accomplish this problem. It looks as if to accomodate Windows you'll have to write a peer to peer encrypted bluetooth sharing service from scratch.